# New Pi 3 has red light lit

Tags: pi-3

Just got a new Pi3 from the gf, and having a lot of troubles with it. One of the issues is that the red light on the Pi is on. I've tried changing the micro SD card and bought a new power supply but it's still lit. I'm currently running Openelec so that the gf can use Kodi. I have a second Pi3 that the mother-in-law is using that has the same issues.

Kodi works, but it's unresponsive, hangs, buffers, and can't play anything in HD. I don't think that the issue is the network, since the Pi2 didn't have this issue, though it did use a WiFi dongle.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The red light means it's getting power. If your Pi is having trouble and hangs, you may want to reflash your SD card, it may have been corrupted. You are doing a software shutdown before pulling the plug, right?

Also keep in mind that the Pi3 needs a newer OS than what was available at the time of the Pi2's release, since it's a different chip and needs different drivers. Make sure your version of Openelec supports the Pi3, which, according to [this link](http://openelec.tv/news/22-releases/175-release-openelec-6-0-2-released) needs to be version 6.0.2 or later.